# Dataframe - put a column as a variable

Tags: r

I would appreciate if you could help me with this little problem.
I have this dataframe:

```
> dxmale
  Var1 Freq
1  F20    1
2  F25    3
3  F31    1
4  F32    5
5  F33    9
6  F34    3
7  F41    3
```

The problem is I want the "Var1" column to be the variables, like if it was a table. I want this in order to `merge` this dataframe with other.
I would like to obtain something like this:

```
> dxmale
   F20 F25 F31 F32 F33 F34 F41
    1   3   1   5   9   3   3
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use `setNames` (or just `names`)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(df <- data.frame(Var1 = letters[1:3], Freq = 1:3))
#   Var1 Freq
# 1    a    1
# 2    b    2
# 3    c    3

setNames(df[,2], df[,1])
# a b c 
# 1 2 3
```